# Does the compiler discard empty methods?

Tags: c#, optimization

Would C# compiler optimize empty void methods away?
Something like

```
private void DoNothing()
{
}
```

As essentially, no code is run aside from adding `DoNothing` to the call stack and removing it again, wouldn't it be better to optimize this call away?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Would C# compiler optimize empty void methods away?

No. They could still be accessed via reflection, so it's important that the method itself stays.

Any call sites are likely to include the call as well - but the *JIT* may optimize them away. It's in a much better position to do so. It's basically a special case of inlining, where the inlined code is empty.

Note that if you call it on another object:

```
foo.DoNothing();
```

that's *not* a no-op, because it will check that `foo` is non-null.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think about null calling a method and therefore failing

Comment: If your entire project never uses reflection can't it then omit it ? Thought it would be smart enough to clean up? I have a lot of empty override methods for example.

Comment: @WDUK: How would it know whether you might call something *else* that uses reflection? It seems very error-prone for a pretty tiny optimization.

Answer (score 3):

If you want you could intercept the post build event for every project and run an IL inspecting tool that will reflect your generated dll, inspect every methodinfo in your type and request it's IL looking for empty IL patterns like only NoOp IL instructions, and remove the unwanted methods.

For example:
var ilBytes = SomeMethodInfo.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();

> A good obfuscation tool will "prune" methods in this way. preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/features#pruning –  weston 5 mins ago

You could use the tool externally of visual studio to find empty methods and remove them from the file they are defined or used in.

Comment: A good obfuscation tool will "prune" methods in this way. http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/features#pruning

Answer (score 2):

Never. Compiler doesn't has to do with what's empty or not written. Its just what you write, you get in your MSIL. you can check it here in **ILDASM**

[image]